# How range and phrase query work in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, inverted-index, range-query

If elastic search is using inverted index, I want to know how elasticsearch is able to support range queries and phrase queries.
Note: I saw that inverted index supports them but i am not clear on how they do it internally.

Answer (score 4):

Found the link .. 
Reference : https://blog.parse.ly/post/1691/lucene/
Here’s a snippet from Lucene in Action on the topic: “If you indexed your field with NumericField, you can efficiently search a particular range for that field using NumericRangeQuery. Under the hood, Lucene translates the requested range into the equivalent set of brackets in the indexed trie structure.”
This blog actually has some nice information on lucene indexes.